# Web socket connections with @stomp/stompjs in React Native

Tags: react-native, websocket, stompjs

I am still new to React Native , i am currently working on project that requires to implement a websocket connection in React native app and subscribe to the topic to receive messages from the websocket. When i tried to implement it using **@stomp/stompjs** i am not able to connect to the websocket the onConnect function doesn't work.

Below is my code

```js
import { Client, Message } from '@stomp/stompjs';
const stompConfig = {
    connectHeaders: {},
    brokerURL: "ws://203xxxxxxxx/xxx/connectSocket",
    debug: function (str) {
        console.log('STOMP: ' + str);
    },
    reconnectDelay: 200,
    onConnect: function (frame) {
        console.log("connected")
        const subscription = stompClient.subscribe("/topic/public/" + userId, function (message) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(message.body));

        });
    },
    onStompError: (frame) => {
        console.log('Additional details: ' + frame.body);
    },
}
stompClient = new Client(stompConfig);
useEffect(() => {
    stompClient.activate();
}, [])
```

Here is the output log I get

```
LOG  STOMP: Opening Web Socket...
LOG  STOMP: Web Socket Opened...
LOG  STOMP: >>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.0,1.1,1.2
heart-beat:10000,10000
```

Any help would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys after doing some research i found the solution apparently there is some type of bug in **@stomp/stompjs** for react native you can view about the issue [here](https://github.com/stomp-js/stompjs/issues/89)
I fixed my problem by adding this line of code to my **stompConfig**

```
stompConfig:{
...,
forceBinaryWSFrames: true,
appendMissingNULLonIncoming: true,
}
```